I encounter the error xmlsec.InternalError: (-1, 'lxml & xmlsec libxml2 library version mismatch')
When I run sentry devserver --workers on my computer, I encounter the error xmlsec.InternalError: (-1, 'lxml & xmlsec libxml2 library version mismatch'). My computer is running MacOS m3 pro, with the following versions installed: lxml 4.6.5, xmlsec 1.3.14, and libxml2 2.12.7.
How should I handle this? Thanks.
I tried reinstalling libxml2 but it didn't work.

As the error message told you, the lxml version is  mismatch.
python -m pip uninstall lxml

Than install the lxml V5.2.2
python -m pip install lxml


I had to install xmlsec=1.3.13. I solved it by installing the wheel file. Thank you.

With python 3.11 and the new xml version it should work, because also XMLSec 1.3.14 works on my machine.
